# USB Drive Bulk Copy Failure Windows 10 + 7

Tags: usb, robocopy

1. I'm trying to copy about 60 GB of files off a 64 GB USB drive onto a new 128 GB USB Drive under Win10 using robocopy. I can copy about 50GB but then the copying stops, without reporting any errors. Win Explorer say the target drive still has > 50% free space but if as a test I try to manually create a new folder in it there is an error message "An unexpected error is keeping you from creating this folder"... "Error 0x8000FFFF".
   I've tried many of the suggested remedies for this error code, e.g. checking permissions but none have fixed it.
   Similar behaviour from this drive is seen on another Win10 and a Win7 which seems to indicate the the problem must be in the USB memory stick not the OS.
   Anyone seen this before, any fixes,suggestions?

Comment: Regrettably, there are intentionally mislabeled USB drives, with **apparent** size far more than actual capacity. See https://www.instructables.com/Dont-fall-for-the-Flash-Drive-Scam!/ , for example. Return the drive for credit, if you can, and if not, publish on the web where it was purchased so others aren't scammed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for taking time to reply.
Before starting I used a utility called 'H2testw' which tests the memory by writing a series of 1GB blocks of random data across the entire volume, then reads them back. According to that there is 117GB of usable space all of which it successfully tested. Assuming this utility actually does what it says, this seems to eliminate this being a counterfeit or faulty drive?